# Sum of values across a line?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, summation

I've been thinking recently and have confused myself a little bit as to the difference between sums and integrals.

I understand that an integral is a Riemann sum where you take the limit as the difference in whatever you are integrating with respect to becomes infinitesimally small.

However, I was thinking recently about how one would sum up all the values along a line/curve. For example, let's say I have a function f(x) that takes in a point and gives the electrical charge at that given point (Assume we are talking about a one dimensional system that just has x values). How would I sum up all the charges along a given interval [a,b].

I initially thought this would be an integral, but wouldn't that give the area under the curve because you are multiplying by $dx$, which isn't exactly what we are looking for? Unless it is, which is why I'm confused as I can't tell if that's what I would want for this situation.

Another thing that is obvious is to literally just add up all the values such as:
$$f_1(x) + f_2(x) + f_3(x) + \ldots f_n(x).$$

This seems to be more of what I might be thinking about but what would be a way to do this "algorithmically" so to speak, where you don't have to literally add up an infinite amount of numbers.

Would you just us a normal sum, or would there be a different way?

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate on adding up charges. Because, at least to me, I lack the engineering background to be confident about a solution. A guess would be that one should add the charges by what proportion of the line they exert their charge. E.g. A line $[0,1]$ with charge $1$ on $[0,1/2]$ and charge $0$ on $(1/2, 1]$ would have a "summed up" charge of $1/2$ (that is the area or integral of the charge over $[0,1]$). This would also suggest the integral in general, as it informally, and sometimes exactly, gives the sum of values by their proportion on the line.

Comment: I feel quite confident saying that adding up the charge at all points is incorrect. If the charge is 1 at each point, you would by adding the charge at each point conclude that there is infinite summed up charge in the line…(would probably solve most energy crises in the world)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function $f(x)$ represents the linear charge density (ie. the amount of charge per unit length), then the total amount of charge $Q$ along the line from $a$ to $b$ is given by the integral

$
Q=\int_a^bf(x)\,dx
$

You can see this from dimensional analysis: since $f(x)$ has dimensions of $\mbox{charge/length}$, then the "area" under $f(x)$ (the integral above) correctly has dimensions of

$
(\mbox{charge\length})\times\mbox{length}=\mbox{charge}
$

If you're familiar with the Dirac delta function, the "charge density" of $n$ discrete points located at $x_1,...,x_n$ between $a$ and $b$ and carrying charges $q_1,...,q_n$ is

$
f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^nq_i\delta(x-x_i)
$

In this case, the integral gives

$
\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=\int_a^b\sum_{i=1}^nq_i\delta(x-x_i)\,dx=\sum_{i=1}^nq_i
$

ie. it is just the total charge you would get by adding up all the individual charges.